# Does retarded interaction of magnet and coil violate energy conservation?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation

Suppose we have a magnet and coil at sufficiently large distances apart such that any movement of magnet can not be known instantaneously at the coil, as change in magnetic field travels at the speed of light. Now, if i give magnet some kinetic energy. After moving to some distance at constant velocity , i will stop magnet by storing its kinetic energy in a flywheel (in form of rotational energy). so magnet will come at rest.

During the motion of magnet, it won't feel any resistance (due to lez's law) because signal, that magnet has been moved is not reached at coil yet. When this change in magnetic field reaches to coil and it will generate current opposing motion of magnet. But, magnet is already at rest so when this opposing magnetic field will reach at the magnet, the magnet will gain kinetic energy in opposite direction and this be will in turn produce current in coil again.

In this whole process, our input energy is not lost because magnet have not felt any resistance during its motion at constant velocity and we stopped magnet by storing its kinetic energy into flywheel . But still we are able to produce current in coil. Isn't this violating energy conservation law ?

Comment: When you store the kinetic energy in the flywheel what have you done with the linear momentum that the magnet had and where did the angular momentum of the flywheel come from?

Comment: We are just converting motional energy of magnet into rotational energy. so magnet will come at rest and flywheel will have its energy in form of rotational energy.

Comment: *"During the motion of magnet, it won't feel any resistance"* - have you considered the time during which the magnet is accelerated?

Comment: Magnet accelerates two times ( at the starting and ending of motion ). In between it will move at constant velocity. I know at starting and ending point it will feel resistance, but only that resistance can not account for output energy that we are getting. Because when magnet is moving with constant velocity, it will not feel any resistance but still coil will produce power.Moreover, Input energy should depend on how much current we draw from the coil. Here in this case, drawing more current will not increase our input energy.

Comment: *"Input energy should depend on how much current we draw from the coil."* - if that were true then the power input to an antenna should depend on receivers arbitrarily far away which isn't the case.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri.....consider simple magnet and coil arrangement, when distances are not large. When you draw more current from coil, that current will impart more resistance on magnet's motion. So you have to increase your input mechanical energy to increase electrical energy. But in our case, since magnet is not feeling any resistance force from coil, drawing more output from coil will not cost you any further input energy.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you have in mind when you write *"drawing more output from coil"*.  Suppose I have a [loop antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna) here and you, in the far-field of the antenna, move the magnet as you describe.  How do I *draw more output from* the antenna?

Comment: Suppose you have a coil. Now if you move magnet it will generate voltage. For a fix voltage, if you decrease resistance of a coil then current will increase. So you can draw more power output ( V*I ).

Comment: It seems to me that you're assuming a contradiction that is this:  the coil is both closely coupled (essentially all of the changing magnetic field threads the coil) and not closely coupled (the coil is light-seconds from the magnet).  If the magnet's start, motion, stop all takes place *before* the magnetic field at the coil begins to change, the coil is not closely coupled and one must take into account both that (a) the electromagnetic field contains and transports energy and (b) most of the changing magnetic field does not thread the coil (unless you also involve a magnetic material).

Comment: Yes, i agree magnetic fields contains and Transport energy. But this energy should come from work done on the magnet. In closely coupled case it comes from the mechanical work that you are doing on magnet against resistance force. But in our case, magnet is not feeling any resistance from coil. So that work done from our side is missing in our case. If this work done is missing here, then how input energy ( mechanical energy from our side ) will be equal to output energy in coil ?

Comment: Right, it's not closely coupled but you seem (to me) to be assuming that the coil 'produces' the same energy that it would if it were.

Comment: How much power coil will produce that depends on what value of resistance we put in the circuit. According to ohm's law current will flow and power will be simply V*I. Since magnet is not going to feel any resistance due to this current, how can input mechanical energy will be equal to output energy in coil ? There is no co-relation between input and output.

Comment: *"How much power coil will produce that depends on what value of resistance we put in the circuit"* - this simply isn't true (it would be if the coil were an ideal voltage source).  This comment thread is too long and likely to be moved to chat but I'm about a done here.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Imagine pushing a magnet through the wire when they are close together. You push the magnet, a current is induced in the coil, Lenz' Law is applied, and a resistive force is felt. The overall kinetic energy, however, is the work you put in to move it minus the work imparted by the electromagnetic force.

In your system, you put kinetic energy into the magnet to move it, then transfer it to the flywheel. **This requires that the flywheel be considered a part of the overall system in which energy is conserved.** The magnet then comes to rest and feels the opposing magnetic force some time later, but the total energy in the overall magnet-coil-flywheel system is the same: the energy of the magnet (now zero) plus the energy in the flywheel (equal to the work initially put in) minus the work done by the electromagnetic force.

Therefore, the total energy is the same as in the first case: the work you put in minus the work done by the electromagnetic force.

Comment: The only input energy we have applied is kinetic energy of magnet. This kinetic energy is stored in flywheel, so it is not lost in producing electrical energy. In the end you have energy stored in flywheel ( which is equivalent to input K.E that we have given to magnet) + electrical energy . Where as our input was only K.E .

Comment: I believe it is a sign issue - the electrical force will be of opposite sign to that of the applied force due to Lenz' Law, pushing it in the opposite direction you are. In the close case, this just makes you push it at a lower acceleration than you would if there was no opposing force (sum the forces: applied force - electromagnetic force). In this case, since you stop applying a force and actively halt the magnet, the effect of the force is to start it moving in the other direction.

Comment: We are giving K.E to magnet then it will run at constant velocity since it is not feeling any resistive forces. After transfering  all its energy to flywheel , our input energy is stored in flywheel. But still we have got electrical energy. Moreover , when opposing force will reach to Magnet, it will gain again kinetic energy in opposite direction and that inturn again produce current in coil. So where did this electrical energy comes from ? Our input energy is already stored in flywheel.

Comment: The purpose of Lenz' Law is to keep consistence with conservation with energy. The idea is that you put work into the system by moving the magnet - now Lenz' Law will act to counter that. It doesn't matter that you moved the energy into the flywheel, the coil will still apply an opposing magnetic force.

Comment: @HemalPansuriya One point that seems to be missing here is the change in the magnetic field. If you move the magnet the $dB/dt$ that travels to the coil is an electromagnetic field, which carries energy. In other words: the magnet radiates. You have to provide this energy as well, and it is definitively not stored in the flywheel.

Comment: @Billy Kalfus...Yes, the coil will apply opposing force on magnet. But in this case magnet won't feel that force during its motion. It will feel that force only after it comes at rest. so at that time it will gain kinetic energy in opposite direction and it will in turn generate power in coil again.

Comment: @mikuszefski ... Magnet will only radiate when it will accelerate. A magnet moving with constant velocity can not radiate any energy . But at constant velocity also it will generate energy in coil. In our case, magnet will accelerate two time ( at starting of motion and ending of motion ) , but in between, magnet will move at constant velocity. Moving with constant velocity also, coil will experience Change in magnetic field and coil will generate energy. At this time it will not radiate anything.

Comment: @HemalPansuriya OK, in your post it is accelerated of course. Nevertheless, the idea must work with a constantly moving magnet as well. Well, what about this. The magnetic field itself has energy (density $\vec B \cdot \vec H/2$). If the current is induced and producing a counter acting field this energy is reduced. Where did it go to? Is it the electrical energy of the current?

Comment: @mikuszefski....magnet moving with constant velocity can not radiate any energy. So, it will not loose its K.E when moving with constant velocity. And yes, field have energy, but in faraday's problem, we always say that energy produced in coil comes only from work done to magnet ( when it experiences resistance force ). Since, in this case, magnet is not feeling any resistance from coil, whatever energy we got in coil is independent of our input energy.

Comment: @HemalPansuriya Once again, I know that a constantly moving magnet does not radiate. and no, if it is outside the light cone, the induced voltage cannot have an effect on the magnet instantaneously, and more no, the energy is conserved as the local energy of the field is reduced. If in a second step the field change comes back to the magnet it is decelerated and it will radiate. Is it possible that you ask something like: "I have a simplified theory that assumes instantaneous interaction. Why does it not work if the setup is so big that it cannot be instantaneous?"

Comment: At the time when magnet is at rest and opposing force from coil reach to magnet, it will gain kinetic energy in opposite direction. This in turn, will again generate current in coil. How energy is conserved in that part ?

Comment: So you are now back to your flywheel experiment, where the magnet decelerated and, hence, radiates. Anyhow, the energy can only come from the local field. I.e. the magnet will accelerate in such a way that the field energy around it is deceasing accordingly. It is the same mechanism that makes a free permanent magnet accelerate in the static field of a fixed permanent magnet: the reduction of magnetic field energy.

Comment: coil's output energy is dependent on how much current we draw from coil. In normal case, when distances are not large, if we draw more current from coil, then magnet will feel more resistance and so we have to give more amount of mechanical input energy to increase electrical energy in coil. But here, magnet is not experiencing any resistance due to coil, so drawing more current will not cost in input mechanical energy. Radiation reaction is not dependent on how much current we draw from the coil. So there is no co-relation between input and output energy.

Comment: @HemalPansuriya Your resistance to reason starts to make this discussion pointless. ...and...current is not energy....for the last time: you cannot argue with an instantaneous description in an retarded phenomenon.

Comment: Power is V*I , so if you increase current, power will also be increased.

Comment: *"Power is V\*I , so if you increase current, power will also be increased"* - @HemalPansuriya, it's frustrating in the extreme to the smart people here that have attempted to point out genuine problems with your thought experiment only to see you reply with an elementary fact that no one here disputes, that no one here doesn't already know, and that isn't relevant to the objections raised.

Answer (score 0):

> In this whole process, our input energy is not lost because magnet have not felt any resistance during its motion at constant velocity and we stopped magnet by storing its kinetic energy into flywheel. But still we are able to produce current in coil. Isn't this violating energy conservation law ?

You forgot to account for electromagnetic energy of the system, which is commonly understood as energy of EM field distributed in the whole space.

The energy conservation only works in EM theory if energy of EM field is taken into account together with kinetic and rest energy of the matter.

In your thought experiment, there is magnetic field everywhere including the space of the coil. When the magnetic field of the magnet begins to change near the coil and electric current in the coil is induced, the current in the coil will create its own magnetic field near the coil. The total magnetic field near the coil will change from its previously established static value, and an electric field will appear as well. The field energy near the coil will change from its previously established static value.

This change of field energy near the coil has to happen in such a way that it will account for any energy extracted (or dissipated) from the electric current in the coil. This follows from the fact that the law of conservation of energy in EM theory is local. It does not matter that the magnet far away will be influenced later. The change of EM field and its energy near the coil happens at the same time the electric current begins to flow.

Comment: Field energy has to come from work that we do on magnet. Since in our case, magnet is not feeling any resistance from coil, so we are not doing any work on magnet when it is traveling at  constant velocity. static field does not create electrical energy, only change in magnetic field does. when distances are not large, the magnet feels resistance from coil and equal amount of work has to be done on magnet. But in our case, we are not doing work on magnet, but still we will get electrical energy in coil.

Comment: Field energy in space near the coil is already there, even before the magnetic field begins to change. It is this local field energy near the coil that will get partly extracted when electric current is flowing in the coil. Work being done on the magnet at the same time has nothing to do with the field energy available near the coil.

Comment: If field energy is extracted, then something must have provided that energy to fields. That energy we generally provide by doing work on Magnet when distances are not large. I agree that field is presant at coil and have energy, but that energy have to come from work done from our side i.e. mechanical energy will convert into electrical energy. In this case , from where did the fields get energy to produce energy in coil ?

Comment: There is field energy all around the magnet ever since the magnet was created. The origin of this energy is in the past, in bodies participating in the process that created the magnet. -- The energy extracted by the coil (say we use the induced current to charge a capacitor) is taken first from the nearby EM field, not from the agent acting with force on the magnet. Only later, when the coil field reaches the magnet, there is some influence on the magnet.

Comment: If the magnet and coil are not very distant, so the coil field reaches the magnet while in motion, we will have to push it to maintain its constant speed. But it is not necessarily true that work of this push force equals energy extracted from the coil at any short time interval (but it should be true after all currents die). The work goes both to increase of EM field energy of the whole system (we are pushing two magnetic poles of the same sign closer together) and to extracted energy from the coil.

Comment: If energy in coil is only extracted from fields (as there is no work done on magnet) , then system's overall energy should decrease. But that is not happening here, because when magnet will be at rest and opposing force will reach at magnet from coil than magnet will gain kinetic energy in opposite direction and that will in turn again generate energy in coil. So, again extra energy will be generated. where is this energy coming from ?

Comment: Again you are forgetting the field energy, this time near the magnet. Generally, whenever there is energy or momentum change of material body as a result of EM forces, this energy and momentum come from the EM field *nearby* the body. As time progresses, changes in field and its energy distribution spread to the whole space, but the first stage involves EM field near the body whose energy/momentum changes.

Comment: If only field is doing work and we don't have to apply any work, than repeating this experiment over and over again we will get arbitrarily large amount of energy.

Comment: @HemalPansuriya, (1) the flywheel will have less (rotational) energy than the energy required for the initial acceleration of the magnet.  (2) Almost all of that difference is in the electromagnetic field.  (3) The rest of the difference has been delivered to the coil.  How is that you propose to extract arbitrarily large amounts of energy?

Comment: @HemalPansuriya, don't forget that the magnet's dipole field goes as the inverse cube of distance.  Assuming the radius $R$ of the (on-axis) loop is small compared to the distance $l$ separating the magnet and loop, the rate of change in magnetic flux threading the loop goes as $1/l^4$.  For $l$ on the order of light-seconds, the rate of change of flux is small indeed, i.e., there is very little induction in the coil.

Comment: > *If only field is doing work and we don't have to apply any work,* But there *is* another work that is being done, namely the work of the non-electromagnetic force pushing the magnet towards and away from the coil. Repeating the experiment will require repeatedly performing work on the magnet, part of which cannot be recuperated.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri &  Ján Lalinský....output from coil depends on us. we can increase the output of coil by increasing more number of turns of coil and decreasing resistance as much as possible. So power V*I can be increased. But this increase of output power will not require us to supply more input energy, because the input is just radiation reaction which magnet felt when accelerated at two times ( at starting and ending of motion ) . This resistance is independent of of what power we draw from the coil, because that resistance is not from the current that is produced in the coil.

Comment: @HemalPansuriya, you're like a broken record; you keeping repeating the same nonsense which is this:  *"output from coil depends on us"*.  This is plainly and simply *false*.  Question:  what is you intention?  Do you aim to convince anyone here that you can extract arbitrary amounts of energy?  Very well then - *do it*.  That will show us a thing or three.

Comment: We can increase the power captured by the coil, but not arbitrarily. We can add more turns,but those will be farther from the magnet and the emf per turn will be lower. If we used more dense turns, self-induction effect will get more pronounced and decrease total emf. -- Your thought experiment with delayed interaction of magnet and coil is certainly interesting, but I recommend you make some numerical estimates of the energy that can be extracted from the field of moving magnet, and how much work is done on the magnet in each cycle.

Comment: @Ján Lalinský .....yes, i will try to do some numerical estimates. Another thing is, if voltage induced in coil is varying with time than we can use transformer to draw more power by following way : suppose voltage produced in coil is V, then step up this voltage by factor of 1000 ( or arbitrarily large ). Suppose resistance connected in secondary is R, so current in secondary winding will be I =1000V/R. And in primary winding current will be drawn 1000*I ( because Ip*Vp=Is*Vs ). So now the power output of the coil will be V*(1000*I) . We have drawn 1000 times more power than previously.

Comment: @HemalPansuriya, in a transformer, almost (ideally all) of the flux through the primary is through the secondary (close coupling) such that neither the source or load 'see' a coil.  In your thought experiment (as I understand it), this isn't even remotely the case *by stipulation*.  I've mentioned this before but you *choose* to ignore it.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri....dear , what i am saying is, use coil as voltage source and connect it to transformer's primary coil. Secondary coil will be obviously close to primary coil.